# Is Thin concurrent if used with Rails / ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency, thin, eventmachine

our Rails 4 app is running in in a `thin -s 16 ...` multiprocess server with Apache as frontend and its reverse proxy handling the internal requests. All works fine and well, the performance is OK for our number of users.

Because everything works just out of the box, I didn't really bother about how Thin actually works. I did stumble about all the Fibers and EventMachine goodness recently though and read up a lot on it.

Thin is using EventMachine for handling Rack requests. So by design it would be able to handle multiple requests in parallel with one ruby process. Unfortunately, while the Thin documentation is functional enough in making you able to run the server in a few minutes' worth of work, it is rather quiet about the internal workings.

Am I correct in assuming that all talk about "concurrency" is moot as soon as I run Thin with Rails? ActiveRecord, the DB drivers, the template processing, etc. are likely not EM enabled, not using Fibers etc., hence will block the single process anyways, while at the same time using most of the server-side processing time in DB-heavy applications.

All my research seems to lead to this conclusion; unfortunately the Thin website/docs say nothing about it. Frankly I am baffled how the word "concurrent" is even entering the picture here...

Can someone clear that up for me? Am I missing some fundamental piece of information, or is the "concurrency" touted on http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/ meant in regards to manually crafted Rack servers which don't use Rails or other "heavy" middlewares?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, when using with Rails it will not be concurrent. Any call to db driver / file system will block the entire ruby interpreter. It may be partially changed in Rails 5, but for now you just need to run a lot of worker processes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.